# Re-sorting array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I don't know why sorting doesn't works with this case:

```
var articolo_generico = new Array();

 var query_example= "select descrizione,quantita,prezzo from table";

          query_sqlite(query_example, function (result) {

              var i = 0;
              for (var index in result) {

                    var obj = result[index];

                    //the object values are strings
                    articolo_generico[i] = {'descrizione': obj.descrizione, 'quantita': obj.quantita, 'prezzo': obj.prezzo};

                    i++;
                    }


              console.log("ARTICOLO GENERICO", articolo_generico);

              articolo_generico = articolo_generico.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a.descrizione > b.descrizione;
              });

              console.log("ARTICOLO GENERICO AFTER SORTING", articolo_generico);

});
```

but sorting works in this case...

```
var articolo_generico = new Array();
articolo_generico[0] = {'descrizione': 'pizza', 'quantita': 5, 'prezzo': 3.00};
articolo_generico[1] = {'descrizione': 'apfelstrudel', 'quantita': 5, 'prezzo': 3.10};
articolo_generico[2] = {'descrizione': 'mojito', 'quantita': 5, 'prezzo': 3.20};
articolo_generico[3] = {'descrizione': 'bacardi', 'quantita': 5, 'prezzo': 3.50};
articolo_generico = articolo_generico.sort(function(a,b) { return a.descrizione > b.descrizione });
console.log(articolo_generico);
```

Link:https://jsfiddle.net/sk5h6j6o/6/

Where is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your comparison function is wrong. The comparison function must return 1 if a > b, -1 if a < b, and 0 if a == b. Your method returns true if a > b, and false (0) if a <= b. So when a < b, the sort function thinks the items are equal.

The correct way to write your sort is:

```
articolo_generico.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.descrizione > b.descrizione) return 1;
    if (a.descrizione < b.descrizione) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

See [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for more details.